# Naming a positive "happy path" test case

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, unit-tests

We have a rather reach set of unit tests for our Python/Django backend. Most of the tests contain a one or more "happy" path tests and a lot of "negative" test cases checking the validation, error-handling, broken pre-conditions etc.

When, most frequently, a test contains a single happy path test though, it is currently just simply a test named `test_ok` (Python unittest method name):

```
def test_ok(self):
    # happy path test here
```

My understanding is that there are certainly better ways to name positive test cases.

What are some of the best practices and things to take into account to name positive tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is one thing I like about good test names is that when it fails on a build-server I can understand what is broken just from reading its name. If the name of the test does not describe what it does it means you need to read the test code to see what is going on.

> When an automated test fails, I want to understand what I just broke — without
>   reading the test code.

Good names are also very helpful for non technical people, certainly if they need to decide on priority of fixing. E.g. do we need to fix this today or can we wait until tomorrow morning when the developers are already out of the zone.

I would pick a similar name strategy as your team uses for their unit-tests, something like: `UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior` for more ideas look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

As if for any function, your test should explain what it does.

*withdraw_is_performed_correctly* | *withdraw_is_not_performed_when_balance_is_not_enough*

*user_is_able_to_logout* | *user_is_not_able_to_logout_if_he_is_not_logged*

etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Intention Revealing**: As with any other test names,happy path tests name should be intention revealing about what functionality it covers.

Think in case of multiple happy path scenarios for same functionality, how by names you can differentiate and reveal the unique 'user journey'(code path) to the reader.

Many times by uniquely naming the tests itself ,we discover test steps redundency.